# Wix - how to customize progress bar to fill smoothly

Tags: wix

We know that WIX progress bar fills up more than once, sometimes twice or thrice by default. But, I am looking out for an alternative method to customize it such that it fills up only once smoothly. The alternative solution on forums say use "Burn aka Bootstrapper" and our client preferably wants a MSI not an EXE.

We are using Wix toolset 3.8.

So is there a better way to achieve a singly smoother filling up progress bar ?

Any samples would be more helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Installer manages that progress bar, not WiX, so there's potentially not much you can do about.

However it can report accurate progress only on activities that it knows the time for. If you run a bunch of custom actions then the install can't know how long your code will run for. Similarly if you call self-registration on COM things Windows can't know how long the code will run for. It doesn't know how long it takes for any of your services to start.

There are things like this if have long running custom actions and you want progress to be accurate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367525(v=vs.85).aspx

Maybe it would help to take a verbose log of the install and match the activities with progress bar reversals or whatever you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes I had referred this link earlier and learning to implement a custom progress bar. Once complete will post my approach whatever it may be. At the same time looking for new approaches.